# Spring Security Authentication without JWT

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner(AuthenticationController authenticationController,
                                               AuthorizationController authorizationController,
                                               AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider) {
        return args -> {
            Spectator spectator = new Spectator("userdemo", "1234");
            Player player = new Player("Khvicha", "Kvaratskhelia"); player.setId(1L);
            Map<String, String> credentials = new HashMap<>();
            credentials.put("username", spectator.getUsername());
            credentials.put("password", spectator.getPassword());
            authenticationController.register(credentials);
            System.out.println(credentials);
            Authentication authentication = authenticationProvider.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(spectator.getUsername(), spectator.getPassword()));
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            authorizationController.addNewPlayer(player);
        };
    }
}
```

Firstly, I register an user and then before calling controller methods, I authenticate users. In this case player is added successfully. But when I try to do the same with postman I fail.

Below is my security configuration. I don't use `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` or JWT authentication.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    private static final String SPECTATOR = Role.SPECTATOR.name();
    private static final String COACH = Role.COACH.name();
    private static final String ADMIN = Role.ADMIN.name();

    private static final String[] WHITE_LIST = {
            "/api/v1/users/auth/**",
    };

    private final AuthenticationProvider authProvider;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfiguration(AuthenticationProvider authProvider) {
        this.authProvider = authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .requestMatchers("/api/v1/users/auth/**").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/api/v1/home/players/create").hasAuthority(SPECTATOR)
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS))
                .authenticationProvider(authProvider);

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

I tried to add form based authentication

```
.formLogin(form -> form
                        .loginPage("/login")
                        .loginProcessingUrl("/api/v1/users/auth/login")
                        .defaultSuccessUrl("/homepage", true)
                        .failureUrl("/login?error=true"));
```

But it didn't work either. I either got infinite redirection loop or 403 error even tho I definitely entered correct credentials.

Comment: First of all FormLogin uses cookies, so you cant set SessionManagment to STATELESS, as form login needs to keep state to be able to logout users. Second of all your 403 is probably CORS which is the most common question here we get about 5 CORS questions a day. I recommend you lookup how to enable DEBUG logs and then read them to get the error for your 403. If it is CORS, there is very convinient chapter in the spring sec docs on their webpage named…. CORS :-O

Comment: Will you please post your authentication provider, so we have the full context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track regarding adding form login, though I think that's probably not what you are looking for, considering you are [publishing an API](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/getting-started.html#security-use-cases).

If you are not using JWT, then there are other options for API authentication like [HTTP Basic](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/passwords/basic.html). Consider the following alternative setup:

```java
@Bean
SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf(csrf -> csrf.ignoreRequestMatchers(new RequestHeaderRequestMatcher("Postman-Token")))
        .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
            .requestMatchers("/api/v1/users/auth/**").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers("/api/v1/home/players/create").hasAuthority(SPECTATOR)
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        )
        .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());

    return http.build();
}
```

When you do this, marking the session as stateless is often unnecessary since the authentication filter for HTTP Basic doesn't access the session in the first place.

Then, when testing in Postman, set up the `Authorization` header with HTTP Basic and the username/password credentials.

Finally, instead of a custom authentication provider, consider a custom `UserDetailsService`; if you share your `AuthenticationProvider` implementation, I'll happily update my answer with more targeted guidance there.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest HTTP basic authentication configuration:

```
package com.example.springbasicauthdemo.configuration;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.factory.PasswordEncoderFactories;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

import static org.springframework.security.config.Customizer.withDefaults;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                        .requestMatchers("/public").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .httpBasic(withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails user =
                User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                        .username("user")
                        .password("password")
                        .roles("USER")
                        .build();

        System.out.println(user.getPassword());

        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```